# Huge gap 37 sec when ubuntu boot

Tags: 16.04, boot

I have a problem with boot speed on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When run `dmesg`

I see there is 37 second delay in a process. Anybody knows why, or how to fix it?

```
[   66.252929] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered listening state
[   66.252948] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered listening state
[   68.113035] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered disabled state
[   68.115645] device virbr0-nic left promiscuous mode
[   68.115665] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered disabled state
[  105.576624] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  105.576632] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  105.576639] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Thanks.

Comment: Virtual bridge? Bridge mode networking for a virtual machine? If you're using a VM; check the networking settings for it.

Comment: I am not sure, but try to find out. Thanks.